# Why not always feel confident enough to speak and share my views in workplace

Tags: communication, colleagues

Some times I come across strange problem which is I didn't feel comfortable enough to speak with persons in my colony or my workplace. At that time I feel feared and even views to share or words didn't comes in my mind and I feel very uncomfortable. This happens only sometimes and not always but I didn't know what can be reason that cause me so feared and uncomfortable even talk with someone.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic. This seems to be a specific issue _you_ are having and we are unlikely to figure out why you are experiencing it - you should talk to someone who can diagnose this issue - a psychologist for example.

Comment: voting Off topic is not a solution. I feel that there will be so many guys that come across such situation and want to know how they improve them self if come across such situation

Comment: This kind of thing is entirely _individual_. I understand your frustration at my comment and vote - but this is outside of what we can help with.

Comment: my behavior most of the time is assertive but sometimes i feel like possessive. assertive, aggressive and possessive are related to every human being nature so i feel that it is a generic problem and not individual and want to know people can overcome if come across such situation

Comment: I have to agree. While this is an issue you face in your workplace, it really isn't something that we are able to help with (with the possible exception of others who have actually dealt with this issue, which would make it too localized rather than off-topic).

Comment: seriously, see a psychiatrist not a bunch of random anonymous people on the internet! You don't seem to have a problem arguing with everyone that this question is *too localized*, it is and *off topic* as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue you are having exists because:

1. You are inexperienced speaking in front of groups which leads to anxiety more often than not.
2. You are not as knowledgeable in a particular topic as you feel you should be
3. You are not adequately prepared to speak in front of a group of people (i.e. you do not plan what you want to say ahead of time)

Fortunately, this is completely normal and happens to everyone at some level.  I think the main thing that can help you in this place is **practice**.

Take some extra time and make a plan for what you want to say in a meeting, establish a goal and work towards that.  Also, make sure you know enough about a particular topic to feel comfortable talking about it or at least know the right questions to ask.

Also, practicing speaking in front of people in general will help you with this as well.  Practice a 30 second elevator pitch of who you are and what you do.  Practice in front of a spouse/friend/mentor who won't judge you and have them give you honest feedback.

Speaking in front of others is a skill that must be practiced and honed.  Even Steve Jobs, one of the best speakers to ever walk the planet practiced obsessively until everything was perfect.